# Batch File: "Environment Variable Not Defined" on a path

Tags: batch-file

I have the following in a batch file

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Wowza\creds.txt") do set %%a
net use J: https://csv/dav %p% /user:%u% /persistent:yes
```

I get an error:

```
 Environment variable C:\Program Files (x86)\Wowza\creds.txt not defined
```

What do I need to resolve this?

Secondly, it works for all colleagues apart from one. Same laptop make, model and build. I used my details and it failed on his but worked on mine.

What fails is that it asks for the credentials to map the drive instead of taking them from the file

**creds.txt**

```
u:JoeBloggs
p:Password1234
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: `set variablename=%%a` you cannot just do `set %%a` as that is asking the system to show you the variable and value of `%%a` in this case which is the content of `creds.txt` You also set `%p%` and `%u%` which I assume you are attempting to get from the creds file? If that is the case this will still not work, I suggest you edit the question and show the content of `creds.txt`

Comment: Have updated with content of creds.txt - the script runs fine but these errors happen

Comment: does it contain the u: and p: as well? as your example?

Comment: I have updated the file with the details - yes, it contains the u and p

Comment: So it is in list format as you just edited?

Comment: Yes, like I've said

Comment: Add `usebackq` to the `for /F` options, currently you are interpreting the text file path as a literal string; see [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html). To correctly assign the variables also change `delims=` to `tokens=1* delims=:`, then replace `set %%a` with `set "%%a=%%b"` (this fails if a username of password begins with `:`!)...

Comment: @aschipfl or he can just change his `creds.txt` file to use `=` instead of `:` i.e `u=username` like his colleagues most probably has as it is working for them.

Answer (score 1):

the reason for your errormessage is, your `for /f` loop doesn't evaluate the contents of the file. It takes a quoted string as string not as filename. `Usebackq` changes that behaviour.

You have another failure in your script: With your code, `set %%a` translates to `set u:JoeBloggs`, which is invalid syntax. Correct syntax requrires `set u=Joebloggs`. Therefore you have to split the line in a part before the colon and a part after the colon and build your `set` command accordingly (just `set %%a` would work, when the contents of the file would look like `u=JoeBloggs`)

Change your `for` loop to:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Wowza\creds.txt") do set "%%a=%%b"
```

Comment: I also suspect the reason why this is working for his colleagues is because their `creds.txt` file is actuall in this format. `u=username` where he utilizes `:` instead :)

Comment: No, exactly the same

Comment: Then it is not the exact same script your colleagues use.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to post a similar answer to @stephan but he beat me to it. If however you have the option to change your `creds.txt` file to the below:

```
u=JoeBloggs
p=Password1234
```

You can shorten the `for` loop a bit to this:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Wowza\creds.txt") do set "%%~a"
```

which effectively just does this:

```
set "u=JoeBloggs"
set "p=Password1234"
```

Comment: Well, this cannot work: `/F` is missing in the first code snippet, and you must use `usebackq` due to the quoted file path...

Comment: @aschipfl yeah true.. forgot I was testing from a variable not file path.